# Reload nginx conf in kubernetes pods

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes container running on GCE.
One of the service is nginx that working as proxy, and with replication controller it hass 10 replicas.
Now i need to change the nginx.conf for some tweaking.
Is there a way for me to reload all the nginx pods?

Right now the only way for me is scale it 0, then scale it up again to 10.
This will cause short downtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rolling update](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/rolling-updates/) which creates a temporarpy replication controller to scale the new version of the pods up, and then scales down the old version afterwards.

In the future, you might want to swtich to using [Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/), which allows declarative deployments.

Comment: Thanks. I read on the kubernetes 1.2.5 changelog, that allow rolling update on same image. Which means allow restart like behavior. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/24645.

Comment: And deployment still in beta, but i will definitely look into that.